# LM35 and Character LCD

Tags: lcd, arduino-pro-mini, temperature-sensor

I have an arduino pro mini and I have attached a 16x2 character LCD and an LM35 analog temperature sensor. When I upload a sketch using only the sensor and send the readings to serial monitor, the readings are OK. When I upload a sketch that displays the readings to the LCD the readings are about 130°C in room temperature. Where is the problem and how can I solve it. Thanks in advance

Code with lcd:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
byte smiley[8] = {
  B00000,
  B01110,
  B01010,
  B01110,
  B00000,
  B00000,
  B00000,
};
// initialize the library with the numbers of the interface pins
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

void setup() {
  // set up the LCD's number of columns and rows: 
  lcd.createChar(0, smiley);
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  analogReference(INTERNAL);
  // Print a message to the LCD.
  lcd.print(analogRead(0)/1024.0 * 500);
  lcd.write(byte(0));
  lcd.print("C");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
  lcd.print("21");
  lcd.write(byte(0));
  lcd.print("C");

}

void loop() {
  // Turn off the cursor:
  lcd.print((analogRead(0)/1024.0)*500);
  lcd.write(byte(0));
  lcd.print("C");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
  delay(5000);
  lcd.clear();
}
```

Only sensor code:

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  Serial.println(analogRead(0)/1024.0*500);
  delay(500);
}
```

Comment: Adding your code would be helpful.

Comment: I think adding code is *essential*...

Comment: I just added it sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you do not keep your code consistent between you temperature test and your LCD test code. The problem lies in your use of the **internal** analog reference, that reference is 1.1V and that is giving you 130°C.

Temp = 260*0.5= 130

The 260 is the ADC reading worked back from the 130°C you gave

To use Internal reference-

Internal ref = 1.1÷1024=0.001074219
That multiplied by one hundred to account for the mV reading of the lm35 gives `0.107` that will give you the correct temp when using the internal reference

[Analog reference](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/AnalogReference) from the arduino site.

If you want to use the analog reading *0.5 comment out the `analogReference()`